# How to use multiple SUM in Eloquent laravel if condition like this

Tags: laravel-5.3

How to make the format query on laravel if I have a sql query like this?

```
 SELECT category,

 SUM(IF(group='core',weight,0))/SUM(IF(group='core',1,0)),

 SUM(IF(group='secondary',weight,0))/SUM(IF(group='secondary',1,0))

 FROM view

 JOIN sub_category USING (id_sub_category)

 JOIN category USING (id_category)

 JOIN gap ON difference = (result-result_sub_category)
```

Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

You have to use DB::raw for the sum, since Laravel doesn't have built-in function for this. Using isn't provided either. So use your model like so:

```
View::join('sub_category', 'sub_category.id_sub_category', '=', 'view.id_sub_category')
->get([DB::raw("SUM(IF(group='core',weight,0))/SUM(IF(group='core',1,0))")]);
```